# An application of Hahn-Banach theorem on the left-shift operator on $l^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

I think this is a fairly standard problem and has been asked about before. However I am mostly interested in getting help with how to close the argument that I have attempted below.

---

**Task**:

The idea is to start with a bounded linear functional on a subspace of $Z \subset l^\infty$ and then invoke Hahn-Banach. The difficult part is choosing the appropriate subspace and functional.

Let $T:l^\infty \to l^\infty$ map $(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ to $(x_2, x_3, \ldots)$.

Write $Y = \{ x - T(x) : x \in l^\infty  \} $

Denote $\boldsymbol{a} := (a,a, \ldots)$ for $a \in \mathbb{C}$.

Show there is a bounded linear functional $f$ from $l^\infty$ to $\mathbb{C}$ such that $f \big( \boldsymbol{1} \big) = 1$, $f(y) = 0$ for each $y \in Y$, and $||f||_{op} = 1$.

$||\cdot ||_{op} $ is the operator norm $\sup \{ |f(x)|/||x||_\infty : x \neq 0 \}$

---

**My attempt**:

I have shown $\boldsymbol{1} = (1,1,\ldots)$ is not in the closure of $Y$.

Take the subspace $Z := Y + \text{span} (\boldsymbol{1} ) = \{ y + \lambda \cdot \boldsymbol{1}  : y \in Y, \lambda \in \mathbb{C} \}$.

If $z \in Z$ then $z = y + \lambda \boldsymbol{1}$ for some $y \in Y$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.

Define a functional $g$ on $Z$ such that $g(z) = g(y + \lambda \boldsymbol{1} ) = \lambda$.

It is immediate that $g \big( \boldsymbol{1}\big) = 1$, $g(y) = 0$ for each $y \in Y$, and $1 \leq ||g||$.

What I am struggling with is showing $||g|| \leq 1$.

---

I can get this if I can show that for any $z \in Z$, with $z = y + \lambda \boldsymbol{1}$, we must have $||z||_\infty \geq |\lambda|$.

Since $\boldsymbol{1}$ is not in the closure of $Y$, neither is $\lambda \boldsymbol{1}$.

I have shown separately that any ball of radius $0 < \epsilon < |\lambda|$ centered at $\lambda\boldsymbol{1}$ does not intersect the closure of $Y$.

This means that the $y$ component in $z = y + \lambda \boldsymbol{1}$ satisfies $ ||y - \alpha \boldsymbol{1} || \geq \epsilon > 0 $.

If the $y$-component of $z$ is zero then we trivially have $||z||= |\lambda|$. But I am failing to show $||z|| \geq |\lambda|$ when the $y$-component of $z$ is non-zero.

I have tried exploiting $ ||y - \alpha \boldsymbol{1} || \geq \epsilon > 0 $ together with the triangle inequality in an intelligent manner but have had no success at all:

$$ ||z|| = ||z - \lambda \boldsymbol{1} + \lambda \boldsymbol{1} || = || y + \lambda \boldsymbol{1} || \ldots \text{dead end}
 $$

I have a suspicion the closing argument ought to be rather simple, but I am not seeing it. Does anyone else?

---

**Proof that for any positive $\epsilon < 1$ and any $y \in Y$, we have $||y - \boldsymbol{1} || \geq \epsilon$**:

Suppose not.

So say $||y-\boldsymbol{1}|| < \epsilon $. Then $|x_n - x_{n+1} - 1|_{\mathbb{C}} < 1$ for each $n$.

Writing $x_n = a_n + i b_n$, we have

$$
|a_n - a_{n+1} - 1 | < \epsilon
$$

Hence
$$1-\epsilon + a_{n+1}< a_n$$

This recurrence relation implies for every $n$ we have
$$ n (1- \epsilon) + a_{n+1} < a_1 $$

But $\{a_n\}$ is a bounded sequence of reals, so $-M \leq a_n \leq M$. This implies

$$n (1-\epsilon) < 2M $$

but the left-hand side can be made arbitrarily large provided $n$ is large enough, owing to $\epsilon < 1$. This is our contradiction.

Thus for any $y \in Y$ and any positive $\epsilon < 1$ we have $||y-\boldsymbol{1}||\geq \epsilon$.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why would you want to apply Hahn--Banach?

Comment: Missed to be explicit about that, have added that now. I want to start with a functional on a subspace and extend it via Hahn-Banach theorem. The subspace and functional are the tricky parts.

Comment: It suffices to show that the distance from $1$ to $Y$ is equal $1.$  Then $\|y+\lambda 1\|\ge |\lambda|.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc ah interesting. I have only managed to show that given any $\epsilon$ such that $0<\epsilon<1$ and given any $y \in Y$, we have $|| y- \boldsymbol{1}|| \geq \epsilon$. That gives me $d( \boldsymbol{1}, Y) \geq \epsilon$. Is the idea now to let $\epsilon \to 1$? E.g. I can take $\epsilon_k = 1 - \frac 1k$ and let $k \to \infty$?

Comment: You have to show that $\epsilon=1.$ See the answer.

Comment: So actually you have solved the problem yourself. I have lready upvoted  your post.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc thank you very much for your help. You brought into my attention that I was missing that I could use what I had already shown in order to show $||y + \boldsymbol{1}|| \geq 1$ for each $y \in Y$. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u\in Y$. We are going to show that $\|\mathbf{1}+u\|\ge 1.$  For  $y:={\rm Re}\,u$ we get $y\in Y$ and $\|\mathbf{1}+u\|\ge \|\mathbf{1}+y\|.$ We have   $y=x-Tx,$
for a unique real valued bounded sequence $x.$ If one of the terms of $y$ is nonnegative then $\|\mathbf{1}+y\|\ge 1.$ Otherwise the sequence $x_n$ is negative and increasing, therefore convergent. Hence $y_n=x_n-x_{n+1}\to 0,$ which implies $\|\mathbf{1}+y\|= 1.$

For $y\in Y$ and $0\neq \lambda\in \mathbb{C}$ we get $$\|y+\lambda\mathbf{1}\|=|\lambda|\, \|\mathbf{1}+\lambda^{-1}y\| \ge |\lambda|$$ Thus $$\|g\|=\sup_{\lambda  \neq 0,y\in Y}{|\lambda|\over \|y+\lambda\mathbf{1}\|}=1$$

Comment: Ah, clever, thank you!

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this argument: We have that for every $y \in Y$ and any $\epsilon$ such that $0 < \epsilon < 1$ that $||y - \boldsymbol{1}|| \geq \epsilon$. Writing $\epsilon_k := 1 - \frac 1k$, we obtain $||y-\boldsymbol{1}|| \geq 1 - \frac 1k$. Hence $1 \geq \inf\{ || y - \boldsymbol{1} || \} \geq 1 - \frac 1k$. Now just let $k \to \infty$ and we get $\inf\{ || y - \boldsymbol{1} || \} = 1$. Does this not work?

Comment: If you can prove that for any $0<\epsilon<1$ we have $\|y-1\|>\epsilon $ then $\|y-1\|\ge 1.$ The main point is the way you prove the first part. Perhaps you can add the proof to OP.

Comment: I have now added a justification of the first proof to my original post